# Laravel: how to make relationship without $hidden attributes?

Tags: laravel, relationship, eager-loading

I have relationship between Post and User

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

And when I show posts with eager load for example

```
$post->with('user');
```

it shows related user but with his $hidden fields, so his encrypted password, remember_token etc. can be seen. How to avoid this? I know it can be done with `select` when defining relationship

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User')->select(array('id', 'username', 'slug', 'description'));
}
```

but is there a cleaner way for doing this?

Comment: Regarding "it shows related user but with his $hidden fields": Where does it show the hidden fields? `$hidden` only applies to JSON output.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, maybe you messed up your $hidden attribute on the User class?
This works out of the box, nothing to be done. In case you're curious, it's all handled by the HidesAttributes trait, which is part of the Model base class.

Since your User class should be a subclass of Authenticatable which is a subclass of Model, you should be good to go. 
Double check your user class.

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
```